# Are spaces allowed after a slash to continue a line (in GNU make)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a Python script wherein I'll need to manually parse the `target: pre1 pre2 . . .` line and I may have targets with multi-line prereqs.

Can a well-written makefile have spaces *after* the `\` (and on the same line as the `\`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Lines.html):

> So, you can format your makefiles for readability by adding newlines into the middle of a statement: **you do this by escaping the internal newlines** with a backslash (`\`) character.
>   ...
>   Outside of recipe lines, backslash/newlines are converted into a single space character. Once that is done, all whitespace around the backslash/newline is condensed into a single space: this includes all whitespace preceding the backslash, all whitespace at the beginning of the line after the backslash/newline, and any consecutive backslash/newline combinations.

So, no, you cannot have any spaces between backslash and newline if your intention is to have line continuation, as then backslash would escape space, not newline character.

It might be of interest that [newline escape handling is different in recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html):

> However, in contrast to how they are treated in other places in a makefile (see Splitting Long Lines), **backslash/newline pairs are not removed from the recipe**. Both the backslash and the newline characters are preserved and passed to the shell. **How the backslash/newline is interpreted depends on your shell**.